# file explorer looks completely different than the pressed file

Tags: java, android

how can I solve this problem.
In the file explorer, when I hit a video file. something else appears in alertdialog. It theoretically should occur, the file pressed.

How can I solve?
Thank you.
I added 2 photos to better understand the error.

```
    public class file_explorer_fragment  extends ListFragment {


    private List<String> item = null;
    private List<String> path = null;
    private String root;
    private TextView myPath;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_file_explorer_fragment, container, false);

        myPath = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.path);

        root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

        getDir(root);

        return v;
    }
    private void getDir(String dirPath)
    {
        myPath.setText("Location: " + dirPath);
        item = new ArrayList<String>();
        path = new ArrayList<String>();
        File f = new File(dirPath);
        File[] files = f.listFiles();

        if(!dirPath.equals(root))
        {
            item.add(root);
            path.add(root);
            item.add("../");
            path.add(f.getParent());
        }

        for(int i=0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            File file = files[i];

            if(!file.isHidden() && file.canRead()) {
                path.add(file.getPath());
                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    item.add(file.getName() + "/");
                }else{
                    if(isVideo(file)){
                        item.add(file.getName());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.row_file_explorer, item);
        setListAdapter(fileList);
    }
    public static boolean isVideo(File file){
//merge perfect codul asta
        /*{
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".avi")) return true;
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".m3u8")) return true;
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".3gp")) return true;
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mpg")) return true;
        if (file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp4")) return true;
        return false;
    }*/



        String extension = "";
        String filename = file.getName().toLowerCase();
        int i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (i >= 0) {
            extension = filename.substring(i);
        }


       /*  String ext = null;
        String s = file.getName();
        int i = s.lastIndexOf('.');

        if (i > 0 && i < s.length() - 1) {
            ext = s.substring(i).toLowerCase();
        }*/


     switch (extension) {
            case ".3gp":
            case ".mpg":
            case ".mpeg":
            case ".mpe":
            case ".mp4":
            case ".avi":
            case ".m3u8":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File file = new File(path.get(position));


        Context context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, path.get(position), duration);
        toast.show();


        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            if(file.canRead()){
                getDir(path.get(position));
            }else{
                new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_folder_open_black_24dp)
                        .setTitle("[" + file.getName() + "] folder can't be read!")
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            }
        }else {
            new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_folder_open_black_24dp)
                    .setTitle(file.getName())
                    .setPositiveButton("OK", null).show();
            //Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("url", root+"/"+file.getName());
            //startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

Photo from show 2 videos.

[image]

Photo 2 show alertdialog, and inside is wrong file.
[image]